# Flows: File Upload component, associating with multiple Ids

Tags: visual-workflow, fsl

We have a flow to be used in a Field Service Mobile App where we have a screen with file upload component. To associate the files with, we are providing `{!Id}` of the Service Appointment, under 'Related Record ID'. This is working fine.

[image]

There is a change in requirement where we now have to associate the same file with Opportunity record. So we have created a variable `{!OppId}` in flow.

Is it possible to provide multiple parameters something like `{!Id}{!OppId}` under 'Related Record ID' to fulfill this requirement? Looks like this isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_screencmp_fileupload.htm&type=5) I don't think it would be possible to as stated in below description of related record id field:

> **Related Record ID**
> Required. ID of the record to associate the files
> with. If no value is passed, the component is disabled.
>
> This attribute accepts single-value resources. The value is treated as
> text.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. create a content document link record variable (cdl)
2. create a Record Collection variable (Object = Content Document Link)
3. loop over .contentDocIds
4. assign values to cdl record var (ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntitiyId (your Opps) and Visibility
5. add cdl record var to the record collection var (step 2)
6. create records with multiple records and assign the collection (step 5).